# How to upload a crossrider extension to Safari and Mozilla Extension store

Tags: firefox-addon, safari-extension, crossrider

I have created a crossrider extension that is working superbly well across all the supported browsers. I could easily install this extension from the download link that crossrider supplys. But as the extension will be used mostly by our clients, how do I get this extension into the Mozilla and Safari extension stores respectively. Crossrider only supplies a ZIP file for the Chrome extension store but not these two others.

Answer (score 3):

I’m happy to hear that your extension is working well using the Crossrider cross browser framework.

Regarding uploading the extension to the respective stores:

- **Safari Store**: To upload the extension to the Safari Store, navigate to the Safari Extension Submission page and use the following information in the specified fields (Where [***ExtId***], [***ExtName***] are your extension id and name respectively):

> **Extension Bundle Identifier**: com.app[***ExtId***]
>
> > e.g. ExtId99999
>
> **Download URL**: http://app-static.crossrider.com/safari/[***ExtId***]/0/0/0/[***ExtName***].safariextz?ver=1.29
>
> > e.g. http://app-static.crossrider.com/safari/99999/0/0/0/My-Ext-Name.safariextz?ver=1.29
>
> **Update Manifest URL**: https://w9u6a2p6.ssl.hwcdn.net/plugin/safari/update/[***ExtId***].plist
>
> > https://w9u6a2p6.ssl.hwcdn.net/plugin/safari/update/99999.plist
>
> **Extension Version**: 1.29

- **Firefox Store**: Crossrider's **Export to AMO feature** is a feature that used to work but due to changes in Mozilla requirements is not currently available. For the latest information, I recommend that you monitor our [changelog](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/guide/changelog) and/or [changelog RSS feed](http://docs.crossrider.com/guides/changelog/rss.php).

[**Disclaimer**: I am a Crossrider employee]